# Rspec authenticate password test fails for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mongomapper

I am learning ruby on rails and mongoDB (mongomapper), and I followed Michael Hartl's tutorial, and encountered a problem. Problem is somewhere in test for authentication of password. When I use console and try authentication it works like a charm, but when running test same test of authentication passes first couple of times and then suddenly fails telling me that password in db and variable doesn't match. Here is the code of tests and message of a test.

*spec/models/special_case.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'pry-debugger'

describe User do
  before do
      @user =  build(:user)
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the error code

```
bojan@bojan-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C:~/rubyprojects/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/special_case.rb 
[DEPRECATION] :index option when defining key "email" is deprecated. Put indexes in `db/indexes.rb`
....F

Failures:

  1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
     Failure/Error: it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }

   expected: #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('53b6b0f6ac04d82c8e000003'), created_at: Fri, 04 Jul 2014 13:49:42 UTC +00:00, email: "boja00@yahoo.com", name: "Bojan Drljaca", password_digest: "$2a$04$Os57kzr4a/1.5Sf5KG5Ib.MV8xThCY0Tok8SiRVC/9b6vK8kiRFTi", updated_at: Fri, 04 Jul 2014 13:49:42 UTC +00:00>
        got: #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('53b6b0f6ac04d82c8e000005'), email: "boja00@yahoo.com", name: "Bojan Drljaca", password_digest: "$2a$04$WGbfIKjDGvK/0nGPaAZXyuiH/z86MVIe0r6TWlQ72mIQw4XmRuR1m">

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -#<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('53b6b0f6ac04d82c8e000003'), created_at: Fri, 04 Jul 2014 13:49:42 UTC +00:00, email: "boja00@yahoo.com", name: "Bojan Drljaca", password_digest: "$2a$04$Os57kzr4a/1.5Sf5KG5Ib.MV8xThCY0Tok8SiRVC/9b6vK8kiRFTi", updated_at: Fri, 04 Jul 2014 13:49:42 UTC +00:00>
   +#<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('53b6b0f6ac04d82c8e000005'), email: "boja00@yahoo.com", name: "Bojan Drljaca", password_digest: "$2a$04$WGbfIKjDGvK/0nGPaAZXyuiH/z86MVIe0r6TWlQ72mIQw4XmRuR1m">

 # ./spec/special_case.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10159 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/special_case.rb:20 # User return value of authenticate method with valid password 

Randomized with seed 5909
```

Test sometimes pass, and suddenly just fails and tells me that password is different (look at hash).

code from debugger

```
[1] sample_app(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1>) »  found_user
=> #<User:0x00000007cc18c8> {
            "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('53b6b7c1ac04d82e9b000003'),
     "created_at" => Fri, 04 Jul 2014 14:18:41 UTC +00:00,
          "email" => "boja00@yahoo.com",
           "name" => "Bojan Drljaca",
"password_digest" => "$2a$04$wg5lDkRFv2u4P90FZ.5EGesNedNr2IifDMiVT/iEU222llk.c8eea",
"updated_at" => Fri, 04 Jul 2014 14:18:41 UTC +00:00
}

[2] sample_app(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1>) »  @user
=> #<User:0x0000000718f040> {
            "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('53b6b7e3ac04d82ea6000005'),
     "created_at" => nil,
          "email" => "boja00@yahoo.com",
           "name" => "Bojan Drljaca",
"password_digest" => "$2a$04$63/jTwT680HDjlQrUP/dVeTwtHb9.PRygGUTj9LoHypEuVesfEm3S",
     "updated_at" => nil
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't have to do with the password.  The expected user has a `created_at` and `updated_at` attribute and the actual user does not.  I guess your `found_user` is never saved?

Another possibility would be testing for the attributes directly rather than the user as a whole:

```
describe "with valid password" do
  let(:result) {found_user.authenticate(@user.password)}

  it 'should fetch the user' do  
    @user.email.should eq result.email
    @user.name.should  eq result.name
  end
end
```

Comment: It is saved, i checked test db in mongo console. created_at and updated_at attributes are inserted automatically with timestamp! in user.rb. Here is the code from debugger, you can see that found_user is saved correctly. The @user is var that is compared (and saved into db) and found_user is from db.

Comment: you should add that code to the original post rather than the comments - it's too hard to read here.

Comment: okay, well it appears that `@user` is not saved - or at least it has `nil` values for `created_at`/`updated_at`, while found use does not.  Will edit my answer